# A json transformation as simple as xslt / saxon

Tags: json, etl, jsonpath

I'm working on an "Extract Transformation Load" project.

In my previous ETL projects, the dataload was structured in XML and I was using xslt for the Transformation part.

For this project, the data is in JSON.

Is there a convenient way to convert one json file into another json file, using jsonpath within a json as saxon is doing it on a single command line?

like for instance : theProgram  -i input.json -t transfo.json -o output.json

```
input.json
{
    "creationDate": "2018-05-29T12:41:08,306+02:00",
    "id": "7edb06eb-2298-34b9-a9f5-cf47f645a6b6", 
    "smartdata":
    {
        "producer": "r2d2"
    }
    "versionSchema": "null"
}
transfo.json
{
    "data": 
        {
            "uuid": "$.id",
            "producer": "$.smartData.producer"
        }
}
output.json
{
    "data": 
        {
            "uuid": "7edb06eb-2298-34b9-a9f5-cf47f645a6b6", 
            "producer": "r2d2"
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it looks like this question hasn't called for a lot of interest. So I've coded my own [jsonpathTransformation](https://github.com/patricerosay/jsonpathTransformation) available for all on the git

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap json with xml and use saxon for that. Kind of hack, but quite simple and should work.